# What to look for in a good electric chainsaw?

Tags: trees, tools, chainsaw, electric

I will need it for clearing large tree limbs and small trees, mostly for storm cleanup in a medium sized yard surrounded by mature, healthy trees.

I am looking for recommendations for safety and convenience features, as well as advice on how to choose the amperage/HP rating and bar length - and also how to tell a reliable model apart from a problem-prone one. Consumer Reports recommends a Poulan Pro 400, but that model seems to no longer be available.

Answer (score 8):

There are many options for electric chainsaws.  I have owned a handful over the years and all have underperformed, but that is to be expected with the exceedingly low prices on the units.

Safety:
Chain brake-  Required in my mind.
Kickback/pull-in teeth- These are the aggressive steal teeth below the bar that are more important than they seem, provide leverage and runaway protection.

Function:
Chain tensioner- must be metal of somekind, and must interact with the chain bar itself.

That being said I have seen only a few electrics with these options checked, and those are on the very expensive side.

I can recommend the Remington and MTD saws ,but I am only recommending them because they are extremely cheap and their replacement is not as difficult.

There is a Stihl MSE 140 C-BQ electric saw that is what you are looking for, but the price will most likely be a barrier, at somewhere over $300.